# get data snapshot to location latitude longitude

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I succed for get data from firestore with this code:

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("location").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Text("Loading Data.. Please Wait");
                return  
                  Container(
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      mapType: MapType.normal,
                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: LatLng("${snapshot.data.documents[0]['latitude']}", "${snapshot.data.documents[0]['longitude']}"),
                        zoom: 12.0
                      ),
                      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                        _controller.complete(controller);
                      },
                    ),
                );
            },
          ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

but I not really uderstand how to put value in LatLng(**error in here**), that is error.
anybody have the idea for that problem, appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [google_maps documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter), I can see you have to pass 2 double values to LatLng constructor. 
Try the code below:

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("location").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Text("Loading Data.. Please Wait");
                return  
                  Container(
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      mapType: MapType.normal,
                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: LatLng(double.parse("${snapshot.data.documents[0]['latitude']}"), double.parse("${snapshot.data.documents[0]['longitude']}")),
                        zoom: 12.0
                      ),
                      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                        _controller.complete(controller);
                      },
                    ),
                );
            },
          ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

The difference is that I used double.parse() to convert your data to double and then I pass it to the LatLng constructor.